# Is there a way to get a custom control to display the correct language in the VS Editor when a different language is selected

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, localization

I know this sounds knit picky but I have several custom controls that have been translated. When I use those controls on a Form and then change the language they still display the default language. When the application is running, the correct language is shown, but this gives the impression that parts of the form are not translated, plus in some circumstances it affects the layout of the form that can not be seen until run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is overriding the OnPaint event of the Custom Control. Or you will have to translate the resx by using a proper resx Editor like [this](http://resxtranslator.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resx/).

For example...

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
        this.Text = CustomGlobalResources.GetItem(this.Tag.ToString());
    }
```

Here is an interesting [addin](http://www.jollans.com/tiki/tiki-index.php?page=MultilangVsNetQuickTourForms) for visual studio.